# Child_added gets triggered after deleting a child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning how to work with Firebase and I have a simple code that adds and remove objects.

The issue is that whenever I remove a child, the `child_added` event would be triggered, with a snap of the last item (after the removal).

How can I prevent this?

```
dbPointer.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', snap => addObjectFromFirebase(snap.val()));
dbPointer.on('child_removed', snap => updateRemovedChild(snap.val()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way the listeners work - they will trigger when they are supposed to trigger, unconditionally.  What you can do is decide, at the time they trigger, if the received snapshot is something you're interested in acting on.  If that's not sufficient, then consider restructuring your data in a way that suits what your client code is trying to do.